# Extracting road curves from an image

Tags: image-processing

I have taken several gps readings while driving around town.

```
gpsPositions=GeoPosition[{{33.657, -84.5197}, {33.6687, -84.4977}, 
{33.692, -84.4907}, {33.7057, -84.4287}, {33.7431, -84.4027}, {33.7285, 
-84.3493}}]

map = GeoGraphics[GeoMarker[gpsPositions], 
  GeoRange ->Entity["City",{"Atlanta","Georgia","UnitedStates"}],ImageSize->Large]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Were are able to extract the main roads by the following functions:

```
    bgnd = GeoGraphics[ GeoRange ->Entity["City",{"Atlanta","Georgia","UnitedStates"}],ImageSize->Large];
    roads = DeleteSmallComponents@
      Thinning@ImageAdd[
        Dilation[#, DiskMatrix[3]] & /@ 
         DominantColors[bgnd, 7, {"CoverageImage", "Color"}][[5 ;; 6, 1]]];
    ImageCompose[map, ColorNegate@SetAlphaChannel[roads, roads]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Road Extraction worked fine. Now convert the gpsPositions and map them to the road image.

```
range = Abs[#1 - #2] & @@@ map[[8, 2]]    
origin = #1 & @@@ map[[8, 2]];
max = Reverse@ImageDimensions[roads];
waypoints = gpsPositions[[1]];
points = Reverse@(Round[(max (#)/range), 1]) & /@ ((# - origin) & /@ 
     waypoints);
Show[ColorNegate@roads, 
 Graphics[{Red, PointSize[Large], Point[points]}]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

I would like to be able to segment the lines between the dots. Then, set up an interpolation function between each dot so we can simulate the placement of the vehicle at any point of the road as needed.

Any thoughts on how this can be achieved?

Comment: `range` appears to be undefined.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure what you want: "segmentation" has a well-defined meaning in image processing, and I think that's not what you want. Also, I couldn't reproduce your results (I think `DominantColors` isn't guaranteed to give the same order or even the same results every time it's run). So this may or may not help...

First, this seems more reproducible than `DominantColors`:

```
roadColors = List @@@ {Yellow, Blue};

colorDist = 
  Total[(# - 
        Transpose[
         ImageData[bgnd][[All, All, ;; 3]], {2, 3, 1}])^2] & /@ 
   roadColors;

roads = Thinning[
  MorphologicalBinarize[
   Closing[Image[1 - MapThread[Min, colorDist, 2]], 
    DiskMatrix[3]], {0.43, 0.8}]]
```

Next, I convert the white pixel locations to a graph:

```
whitePixels = PixelValuePositions[roads, 1];

nearestFn = Nearest[whitePixels -> Automatic];

edges = MapThread[
   Function[{point, potentialNeighbors}, 
    point <-> # & /@ 
     Select[potentialNeighbors, 
      0 < EuclideanDistance[whitePixels[[#]], whitePixels[[point]]] < 
        2 &]],
   {Range[Length[whitePixels]], nearestFn[#, 10] & /@ whitePixels}];

g = Graph[DeleteDuplicates@Flatten[edges]];
```

Now, if I choose point locations in the image:

```
pts = {{133, 97}, {464, 461}};
LocatorPane[Dynamic[pts], ColorNegate@roads]
```

I can use `nearestFn` to find the nearest road pixel, and `FindShortestPath` to find the shortest path between two points:

```
path = FindShortestPath[g, nearestFn[pts[[1]]][[1]], 
   nearestFn[pts[[2]]][[1]]];

Show[Image@bgnd, 
 Graphics[{Red, Line[whitePixels[[path]]], PointSize[Large], 
   Point[whitePixels[[path[[;; ;; 10]]]]]}]]
```

[image]

We can even make a little Indiana Jones-style animation:

```
Animate[Show[Image@bgnd, 
  Graphics[{Red, Thick, Line[whitePixels[[path[[;; i ;; 2]]]]]}]], {i,
   1, Length[path], 1}]
```

(unfortunately, I don't think I can upload videos to Mathematica.SE)

Comment: I'm getting the error `Nearest::dmtch: The dimension of... does not match` when evaluating the second code block.

Comment: @Nikie, this is what I wanted to achieve. Thx. I'll be checking the code a wee bit later. Any recommendation for changing the title to something more meaningful?

Comment: @Nikie, have you done anything special with the definition of bgnd? I get the following error message Show::gcomb: Could not combine the graphics objects in Show

Comment: @Zviovich: I've used `bgnd=Image[bgnd]`, to make my experiments with `colorDist` faster. I didn't realize this changed the behavior of `Show`. I've updated my answer. Regarding the title: Maybe something like "Extracting road graphs from an image"?

Comment: @Pickett: Weird. I've just executed the code in a fresh MMA session, and except for the `Show`-problem Zviovich mentioned, it worked fine. Does `whitePixels` contain a list of 2d coordinates in your session? Or maybe `-> Automatic` syntax is newer than your MMA version?

Comment: I have 10.0.0.0. It works if I replace `nearestFn[whitePixels, 10]` with `nearestFn[#, 10] & /@ whitePixels` so perhaps `NearestFunction` became `Listable` in one of the later patches.

Comment: @Pickett: Weird. The documentation doesn't say that this syntax is new, and I could have sworn I've used it like this since v8. OTOH, the speed difference isn't that large (in this case) so I'll change it to your version.

Comment: @nikie loved the method used to make the road system stand out. Do you have any recommendation on literature to read to learn the tricks available in the discipline of image processing?

Comment: you can post animated gifs instead of videos

Comment: @P.Fonseca: I tried, but exported as gif the animation was ~30 MB... (swf and qt were both between 1-2 MB)

Comment: @NikiEstner I really like this solution. Would you consider a contribution to our editorial column http://wolfr.am/StaffPicks ?