# Mathematical morphology: removing text features from image, while keeping connectivity

Tags: image-processing

I have this image of London's road networks.
[image]

```
img = Image[
  Import["https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=+51.5+\
-0.116667&zoom=10&size=600x600&scale=2&style=feature:road.highway%\
7Ccolor:0x000000%7Cweight:1%7Cvisibility:on"], ImageSize -> Medium]
```

After Binarize[] and ColorNegate[]:
[image]

I want to take out:

**a)** The text, without disrupting the edge connectivity.

**b)** The rectangles, again, without breaking edges.

How can I do this?

After binarizing and negating the image, I tried using MorphologicalGraph

```
Image[MorphologicalGraph[blackLondon, EdgeStyle -> Black, 
  VertexStyle -> White]]
```

and got this unsatisfactory result:

[image]

I also tried binarizing from 0 (the roads that I care about are pure black) and got this:

```
binarizedLondon2= Binarize[img, 0]
```

[image]

At this image, I applied morphological closing with a DiskMatrix, and managed to identify the rectangular elements.

```
 rectangularElementsMask3 = 
 ColorNegate[Closing[binarized2, DiskMatrix[3]]]
```

[image]

I clean it up with an Opening.

```
rectangularElementsMask4 = 
 Opening[rectangularElementsMask3, DiskMatrix[7]]
```

[image]

then Inpaint, on the binarized image

```
Inpaint[binarized2, rectangularElementsMask4]
```

and get this result, which is still disconnected.

[image]

Comment: +1 on an interesting question - there are some IP wizards here, s/b interesting to see what they come up with...

Comment: Try `ContourDetect[Threshold[img, .9]]` where img is your second attached image - gets *mighty* close to keeping roads cleanly connected. I'd venture with some masking for the rectangles, and then a filter run over the rectangle-removed version, with the rectangles again as masks, that looks for "dangling ends" and connects them with a line would be quite nice...

Comment: `MorphologicalPerimeter[img, .9]` on same second image is also looking like a pretty good start.

Comment: Related: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/77972/extracting-road-curves-from-an-image

Answer (score 20, accepted):

`MorphologicalBinarize` and `ColorNegate` it. We use `Manipulate` to choose the finest parameter.

```
img = Image[
    Import["https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=+51.\
    5+-0.116667&zoom=10&size=600x600&scale=2&style=feature:road.highway%\
    7Ccolor:0x000000%7Cweight:1%7Cvisibility:on"], ImageSize -> Medium];

Manipulate[
  img2 = DeleteSmallComponents@
   ColorNegate[MorphologicalBinarize[img, {x, y}]], {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 
1}]
```

[image]

Then we dilate `img2` and find the largest connected component. `Manipulate` is used here again for parameter issues. To better show the result, we combine the detected roads with the original map.

```
Manipulate[
 r = Dilation[img2, x] // 
   MorphologicalComponents[#, CornerNeighbors -> False] &; 
    road = Commonest[Flatten[r], 2][[2]]; 
 ImageAdd[img, 
  ColorReplace[
   Dilation[
    img3 = Pruning[
  Thinning@Image[r /. {road -> 1, x_ /; x != road :> 0}], 10], 1],
    White -> Red]], {x, 0, 3}]
```

[image]

The final result.

[image]